# How to get data in array JSON many layers

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I want get created_at(video), start_at(live) in lessons to display a web page. But data is nested 4 layers, how to write code JS get api data ?

JSON file

```js
"courses": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "title": "title 1",
        "sections": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Section 1",
                "lessons": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "title": "title live",
                        "live": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "start_at": "2022-01-31 00:00:00",
                            "end_at": "2022-01-31 00:00:00",
                         },
                         "video": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "created_at": "2022-01-31 00:00:00",
                            "end_at": "2022-01-31 00:00:00",
                         }
                    }
                 ]
         }
    }
```

I'm using a forEach loop to get data  from item.sections.lessons but it doesn't working

VueJS file

```js
data() {
  return {
    eventCourse: [],
    lessonsCourse: [],
  }
 },
 mounted () {
   this.getData()
 },
 methods: {
   async getData () {
     try {
       const request = await Axios.get('/v1/courses')
       this.eventCourse = request.courses
       this.eventCourse.forEach(item => {
          this.lessonsCourse = item.sections.lessons
       });
     } catch (error) {
       console.log(error.message)
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Or, to access all `live.start_at` and `video.created_at`, `courses.map(c => c.sections.map(s => s.lessons.map(l => ({courseid: c.id, sectionid: s.id, lessonid: l.id, live_start_at: l.live.start_at, video_createdat: l.video.created_at})));`

Answer (score 0):

Your `lessonsCourse` property gets overwritten in each `forEach` cycle.

You can use spread operator to concatenate the section lessons array to your main array:

```
this.eventCourse.forEach(course => {
  course.sections.forEach(section => {
    this.lessonsCourse = [...this.lessonsCourse, ...section.lessons];
  });
});
```

Or, if your compiler doesn't support spread syntax using push:

```
this.eventCourse.forEach(course => {
  course.sections.forEach(section => {
    section.lessons.forEach(lesson => {
      this.lessonsCourse.push(lesson);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: `course.sections.lessons.forEach` --> `sections`? Or, may be `course.section.lessons.forEach`.

Comment: @jsN00b By the look of the json, courses and sections are arrays, so I'm assuming there are several of them to iterate through. If not something like `courses[0].sections[0].lessons.forEach()` would work.

Comment: I can get data in lessons to display a web page already. Thank you everyone.

Comment: @Ninowis, in the second code-section (ie, the one under "... doesn't support spread syntax ..."), the third line reads `course.sections.lessons.forEach(lesson => {`. In this line, `sections` may need to be changed and instead `section` may need to be used. This is to explain my earlier comment.

Comment: @jsN00b Indeed! Code updated, thank you :)

Comment: @kwang please consider accepting an answer or add the solution as an answer to this post so others can use it too.